# How to change asp.net chart yAxis label text?

Tags: asp.net, charts

i need to set arabic numbers on y axis for my asp.net chart, but unfortunately changing the font would not help me. So i tried to change the label text by Code, for all labels I want to change the TEXT of labels, is it possible, is there any way? please see my Chart, i want to change the circled part numbers. thanks

[image]

Comment: Please tag your question with the chart library you're using.

Answer (score -1):

You may use label formatter callback function.

```
function Format(label, series) {
  return "your arabic text";
}
```

HighCharts is really good for drawing charts.

http://jsfiddle.net/QQk8Z/3/

Comment: can you post your javascript code that is generating the chart?

Comment: i don't use java script.!! I fill my chart by SQL data source, on server side!!! Actually i am not permitted to use java script!!